# Can't get Lazarus to do.....anything?

Tags: freepascal, lazarus

So I thought I would install Lazarus/Free pascal -latest version from the sourceforge website.

Downloaded the win32 version and install on my XP machine couple of nights ago.

Problem is, it can't seem to find any of its own files.

From the first and every subsequent run it comes up with an error which says it can't find its system.ppu file relating to win32.

I just ignore that error and it seems to still run.

I tried to make a simple calculator application and it couldn't even seem to find the system files or files in the project directory. After battling these problems and setting every single path I could find in all the setups to every directory I could find it eventually compiled and run the program - once, not been able to make it do it again.

I also tried to make a user component library following the instructions on the web and that won't work either because, you guessed it, it can't the files. This time it gives an error saying it can't find a Ttreeview component, despite not even using that component in the library.

Being able to follow search paths is pretty fundamental stuff that they don't seem to have mastered.

Anybody managed to get a working system going, or any tips to sort these problems out?

Comment: I have joined and delegated this question to the Lazarus forum.

Comment: I've _never_ had a problem.  I wonder if you should uninstall it and try again; it sounds like the installation might have been interrupted.

Comment: Andy, have you been able to fix your problem? If so, what was the solution? Inquiring minds want to know...

Answer (score 2):

Did you install in the default directory c:\lazarus? I thought there was an issue with installing to another directory, especially if the path contains spaces.

Comment: Yep, its in c:\lazarus on a clean machine, no previous installation.

Comment: Some editions of binutils have the problem with space btw, not Lazarus itself. The increasing use of own tools on Windows should make this less and less.

Answer (score 2):

Nine times out of ten, its the old config of an earlier Lazarus attempt, that still lingers somewhere in the "local app" part of the profile.

Comment: Perhaps for posterity as the OP probably solved his problem by now(??): this does seem the most likely cause. Try removing your settings, they should be in e.g. c:\users\<username>\AppData\Local\lazarus\ on Vista+ and somewhere equivalent under c:\documents and settings\.. on XP)

Comment: I heard the next major iteration has versioned configs, to be able to warn the user when he is recycling old configs.

Answer (score -2):

If nothing else helps uninstall Lazarus, download **[Lazarus CodeTyphon edition](http://www.pilotlogic.com/codetyphon/help/codetyphon_current_status.htm)**, and run install as admin.

Comment: While CT may be good, the regular Lazarus install should just work (and does, in my experience). If the problems Andy has are caused by the installer and not by him, I think the installer should be fixed.

Comment: And -1 is for what? For trying to help when seeing that he couldn't find any solution for his problem? I said "if nothing else helps" then install CodeTyphon Lazarus version because it has completely different installation method which seams to work when standard one doesn't. The same answer helped many now happy Lazarus users, which would have quit Lazarus simply because it didn't work on their system. Speaking of alternative installation methods, FPCUP might also help and it's worth trying: http://www.lazarus.freepascal.org/index.php?topic=15919.0

Comment: No, Avra, not for that. Though you did try to help, you didn't answer the question he asked. There must be a solution for his problems with his Lazarus install.

Comment: So offering a workaround when no one else offered an answer is rewarded with -1? I don't get it, but never mind. Cheers. Life goes on...